# Javascript If element not exist return, cause object not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when I am checking whether element exist or not.

I'm using `return;` if element does not exist on document. This method cause the **whole object** not working anymore.

look at this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LcwLm5bb/

see this line :

```
$("#notExist").focus(); // this element not exist on document, so I call this below condition

if (id == null) {
    return; // this will shutdown the object for executing other object;
}

// ^ this code will cause next object not working anymore.
$(".child3").html("hahahahahaha");   // <--- not working anymore
```

how to get this things work?
what's the best way for handling this issue?

so, the next object will execute without any problem.

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on that last line.

Comment: @Hatchet Where? A syntax error would show up in the console.

Comment: why return; will cause the whole object not working anymore? even if i instance another object?

Comment: @Siguza It was fixed. See the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're aborting if there is no tag by that ID.
And you're selecting by class name, not ID.

Either, you need to change

```
if (id == null) {
```

into something like

```
if (id == null && cl.length == 0 && tag.length == 0) {
```

or you should rewrite your code to use something like [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LcwLm5bb/6/).

Comment: thanks Siguza for answering, i try your method, but, still not working.

Comment: @ChingChing Sorry, that should've been `.length == 0` instead.

Comment: this works like a champ! thank you so much Siguza, you da real MVP!!

Answer (score 0):

The return construct will halt execution inside the scope of your code.  So if the entire code you have posted is your script then once the return condition is met then anything after that inside the same scope will not execute anymore. Remember that everything in JavaScript is scoped to the function level.

Example:

```
     //call test
     test();

   function test(){

            if(1 === 1){

                 return;//<-- exits the function

            }

     }
```

Comment: thanks larry for answering, i try your method, but stille not working. the next object did not execute.